# 'treatment of the issues' and 'sensitivity to the problems': Why cannot these be Noun Phrases?

Tags: syntax, x-bar-theory

<sub>Source: p 178  *Understanding Syntax* (4 ed, 2014) by Prof. Maggie Tallerman PhD in Linguistics [(U. Hull)](http://www.ncl.ac.uk/elll/staff/profile/maggie.tallerman).

The author is using (84) and (85) to introduce Bar Notation.</sub>

> In (84), *admired* has a slightly different direct object. Here, I bracket the *entire* object NP, but without specifying its internal structure:
>
> (84) I admired [<sub>NP</sub> the director’s treatment of the issues and sensitivity to the
>   problems].
>
> Inside the full NP, two smaller strings of words are conjoined. Unlike in (83),
>   however, the conjoined strings in (84) are not full NPs. [...]
>
> The conjuncts are *treatment of the issues* and *sensitivity to the problems*. If you didn’t
>   get this, think about what (84) means; the specifier (Section 4.1.8) *the director’s*
>   applies to both conjuncts: it’s both the director’s treatment of the issues and her
>   sensitivity that you admire. So within the direct object NP we have two conjoined
>   strings as shown in bold in (85):
>
> (85) I admired     [<sub>NP</sub> the director’s
>   [<sub>**??**</sub> **[1.] treatment of the issues**] and [<sub>**??**</sub> **[2.] sensitivity to
>   the problems**]    ].
>
> If co-ordination is a reliable test for constituency, we must conclude that both of
>   these sequences in bold are constituents. However, they’re not members of any category we’ve seen before, which is why I indicate the category with subscript
>   question marks instead of the real category labels.

The author then states that 1 and 2 are N' (N-bar). But why cannot 1 and 2 be classified as (shorter) Noun Phrases, within the larger Noun Phrase in (85)?

Comment: I'd call them NPs... What does the book go on to say? Surely it wouldn't leave those question marks unanswered.

Comment: @curiousdannii, you can find other examples in which "treatment of the issues" is a NP.  For instance, "Treatment of the issues is always difficult."  But that doesn't mean that this string of words is a NP in the example being asked about.  It cannot be, for the reason I gave in my answer below.

Comment: @curiousdannii I wrote `The author then states that 1 and 2 are N' (N-bar).` in my OP. Does this answer your question, or were you implying that you needed more details?

Answer (score 1):

For one thing, you can't combine a Det with a NP in order to create a NP.  *"[NP the [NP the director] ]". So since the Det "the director's" combines with 1 "[?? treatment of the issues]" to make the NP "[NP the director's treatment of the issues]", you know that 1 can't be a NP.

Comment: Sorry, this just doesn't make much sense to me. Why can't "the director's" be a normal possessor Det of the noun treatment?

Comment: @curiousdannii, You have to find a parse for the entire example sentence.  If "the director's" combines with "treatment" to form a NP, what do you do with the rest of the words?

Comment: It's the complement of treatment and takes the N' position.

Comment: @curiousdannii, I don't know what the "it" in your comment could refer to.  I asked about the rest of the words in *the entire example sentence*. The rest of the words are "of the issues and sensitivity to the problems".  The point of the example is the Det "the director's" is interpreted as being the Det for "sensitivity to the problems".  Please try to work out the structure of the entire example sentence.

Comment: I'd analyse it something like this: [NP the director's1 [N' [N treatment] of the issues]] and [*i*1 [N' [N sensitivity] to the problems]] With a trace for the spec of the second NP

Comment: @curiousdannii, Thank you.  That's a beginning, but it needs work.  For one thing, you haven't parsed the entire sentence.  For another, you can't index a Det, since it doesn't have reference.  And the "and" must connect two phrases of the same category.

Comment: The index is to the NP inside the Det, and the Conj is connecting two NPs (forgot to write that sorry).

Comment: This question might be dependent on whether DP or NP is considered to be the primary category.

Comment: @curiousdannii, But you've treated the index as though it were a NP.  The right way to do this depends on the same principle that tells you "I like forks and ham" implies both "I like forks" and "I like ham".  No index is required.